# Order of jQuery On Events and Triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

See the following:

```
$('body').on('whyhellothere', function(){

    console.log('done...');                                     

});

$('body').triggerHandler('whyhellothere');
```

This snippet returns:

```
done...
```

While if we reverse the order:

```
$('body').triggerHandler('whyhellothere');

$('body').on('whyhellothere', function(){

    console.log('done...');                                     

});
```

This snippet returns nothing. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you shout in the forest, and *then* I come along, I won't hear anything, would I?

You're registering the event handler *after* the event was triggered. A registered handler can only listen to events that are triggered after they start listening.

It's simple physics :P

Comment: Great analogy :) I have to refactor my code slightly now which would make it less intelligible than if order was maintained. Thanks again, i get it now.

Comment: @BilboBaggins - You should've asked Gandalf though. I'm sure he could make me hear what you shouted before I arrived...

Comment: He's always so busy, he doesn't have time for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript gets processed top down.  It doesn't recognize your `on` call as some top-level definition that should be processed before something else.  So you're calling one function that triggers a handler, that function call looks for all currently registered handlers for that event, of which there are none, and then calls them all (of which there are none).  Then you add a new handler to that event listener.  And any calls thereafter will iterate the list of handlers (now 1) and call them.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Cheers!